# How can I return specific matrix rows based on criteria?

Tags: matrix, elementcriteriamodel

So let's say I have the following code. I have the data to retrieve the entry I want, But I only want to return some of the matrix rows based on some criteria.

Example Code:

```
{% set entryId = 1 %}
{% set entry = craft.entries({ section: "mySection", id: entryId }).first() %}

{% set myMatrixOutput = entry.myMatrixField.find({ someFieldInTheMatix: 2 }) %}

{% for row in myMatrixOutput %}
    {{ row.someFieldInTheMatrix }}
{% endfor %}
```

I can't get that to work it simply return me everything. I know that I could adjust my loop to be

```
{% for row in myMatrixOutput if row.someFieldInTheMatix == 2 %}
```

But say I have a large number of rows in the matrix field it would seem a waste to do all that looping if it could just bring back the correct results?

Comment: You example code should work with Craft 2.3 :D

Answer (score 3):

<s>As far as I know, the only criteria to filter Matrix blocks is the `type` property or to pick a block by it's position with `first`, `last` or the new `nth` filter.</s>

Yes, it would totally make sense to have more options to grab select Matrix blocks and I am rather confident that this is s.th. that is already on "The List".

**Update:**

Craft 2.3 change things! Besides using the `type` property or to pick a block by it's position with `first`, `last` or the `nth` filter it is now possible to query for Matrix blocks using all sorts of custom field parameters.

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.slug('myMatrixEntry').first() %}

{# Query Matrix blocks using custom field parameters #}
{% set blocks = entry.myMatrixField.type('text').myLightswitchField('1').myDateField('> 2014-12-02') %}

{% for block in blocks %}
...
{% endfor %}
```