# Lookup row in matrix field by "Name" column?

Tags: templating, matrix

If I have a matrix field with 2 fields "Name" and "Entry" is it possible to lookup the first row in that matrix field which has a specific "Name"?

Context: Twig template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2357/130) the only ways to filter matrix blocks are by type, or by position. So you need to use the `if` condition on the [twig for tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html).

```
{% for m in entry.myMatrix if m.theName == nameImLookingFor %}
  {% if loop.index == 1 %}
    got the first one, it is {{m.theName}}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you don't want to loop over all of the blocks, you can also install the [mnbreakandcontinue plugin](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mnbreakandcontinue) and break out of the loop after the first match:

```
{% for m in entry.myMatrix if m.theName == nameImLookingFor %}
  got the first one, it is {{m.theName}}
  {% break %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: And according to Brandon's comment [here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/39/search-matrix-for-blocks-with-upcoming-dates/41#comment5242_41), things will change with Craft 2.3! Really good news...

Comment: Awesome thanks! and thanks for mentioning the 'mnbreakandcontinue' plugin :)